# Do I need to request the Google-places-api every time a user views a page on my website to show an image?

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I would like to use the google places api to show images on my website pages, in order to determine if we can use this I need to know the exact behavior of this call of the image. Does it mean that every time when a user enters a page to which I have attached the google places images functionality a call needs to be performed in order to show the image?

If so I can determine how much it would cost to make use of this functionality, hence page views are equal to api calls.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Places Photos API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos) has some pretty good documentation.

For each place you want photos for, you first have to make a request to [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) or [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) to retrieve a photos array. Each photo that you want to display would be another request through the api using your API Key and a photoreference from the photos array.

Both types of request could either be made from client side code or from your server. If made from your server, you could reduce the number of API calls made by caching photos arrays and photos for use across many web requests.